# LINQ querying a Dictionary<String, Object> and List<Object>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, dictionary

I have

1) List < objectA > objectAList

objectA has id, name , age, height, weight

2) Dictionary < string, List< ObjectB >> objectBDictionary;

Object B has id, name,  address, email

Now, I would like to extract related entry matching (id and name)  between objectAList and objectBDictionary.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? The StackOverflow community would generally expect a question to show some research effort: please post the code you've already tried.

Comment: I can work with foreach loops and wondered if linq is better off

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Usually, you should provide a description of your problem, as you already did and an effort or more you have made to solve it. For instance, despite the fact you disn't make it to write a linq query that solves your problem, you had to write your solution with foreach loops. Then you should attempt to write something in linq and then ask for help. That's the way SO works. Hope it helps. Below I have provided an answer to you question. But I suggest you read my comment and follow it for your future questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
// Initially, I would get a list of all objectB's in the lists of objectB that
// are contained in the Dictionary values.

List<ObjectB> objectsB =  objectBDictionary.Select(x=>x.Value)
                                           .SelectMany(y=>y);

// Then, I would make the join.
var result = from a in objectListA
             join b in objectsB
             on new { a.id, a.name } equals { b.id, b.name }
             select new 
             {
                 Id = a.id,
                 Name = a.name,
                 Height = a.height,
                 Weight = a.weight,
                 Address = b.address,
                 Email = b.email
             };
```